# Can the cell type be defined independent of the column in pe:sheet?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, spreadsheet, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I am prototyping with pe:sheet to represent different type of cells within a sheet. However my requirements are to have different cell types within one column. Is there a possibility to do this with pe:sheet?

I have a successful prototype using what was written down in the pe:sheet showcase. I can use the component and have different cell types based on the column type definition.

I would like to define individual cell type instead of column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe this is a limitation of the underlying Handsontable where the cell type is defined at the column level.

https://handsontable.com/docs/7.0.0/demo-numeric.html

There may be a way to do it with raw Handsontable but I am not aware of such a way but it may exist.  But I can definitively say it cannot be done with the current pe:sheet.

Comment: Hi Melloware, thank you for the quick feedback. As you have pointed out in the underlying Handsontable seems like there is a cells and cell function where the cell-type can be defined. It is also stated here https://handsontable.com/docs/7.0.0/Options.html#cells.
Do you have any plans on implementing this withing the pe:sheet? Or is it maybe possible to do the definition on row level instead of column level? Thank you

Comment: Probably not as everything with PE Sheet was meant to mirror the PF Datatable even mirroring the pe:sheetColumn to mirror p:column to give people a more efficient version and an editable datatable. To rearrange all the code to be "per cell" would be a significant re-write.  You might be better off just using raw Handsontable JS code if you need the per cell requirements.